# Closed unit ball not homeomorphic to open unit ball

Tags: general-topology

> Question:
>
> Prove that $B_{\epsilon =1}\left ( \vec{0} \right )$ is not homeomorphic to the closed unit ball $\bar{B_{\epsilon=1}}\left [ \vec{0} \right ]$.

I'm having a bit of problem kick starting this question.
I think a counterexample or a contradiction is the way forward.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The image of a compact set by a continuous function is a what set?

Comment: Is a compact set

Comment: Sorry, are we talking finite dimensions here? You need to elaborate the space here, before I consume much more wine...

Comment: @copper.hat well it was not stated. But the preceding question asked for me to show that the open unit ball is not compact in $R^{n}$

Comment: So, the image of the closed ball, which is compact in finite dimensions, is compact, hence it can never equal the open ball.

Comment: that is true. But I'm having a bit of problem trying to show that the closed unit ball is compact. Once that is done, the proof concludes.

Comment: One needs to be a little careful. In the space $B(0,1)$, the open & closed unit balls are  the same, hence homeomorphic.

Comment: Get off your Heine Borel. In finite dimensions, compact **iff** closed & what?

Comment: I was already aware that Heine-Borel just makes things difficult in these scenarios. Closed and bounded.

Comment: Heine Borel makes it simple, surely?

Comment: The comment police will be along shortly.

Comment: The closed unit ball is a closed set. Now, determining that it is bounded shows that it is compact by the HB-theorem.

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: And it is done.